# How to list the total sal of a emp and tsal >1500

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT 
  ename
  ,sal
  ,(sal+comm) AS tsal 
FROM emp 
WHERE 
  tsal > 1500
;
```

getting error in the where clause, 
when I use 'where (sal+comm)>1500' it is working properly.

Can't we use alias name in the where condition?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use column alias in `WHERE` condition; rather use the same expression/calculation in your `WHERE` condition like

```
select ename,sal, (sal+comm) as tsal 
from emp 
where sal + comm > 1500
```

You can as well use a outer query/inline query, to use the alias as column

```
select * from
(
select ename, sal, (sal+comm) as tsal 
from emp 
) tab 
where tsal > 1500
```